# Fixed width text + fluid boxes horizontally

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

## What i want

[image]

DIV with text should be as wide as it needed for text.

Bar DIVs should be as wide (with equal width) as it needed to take all of the rest space. DIVs are added dynamically, so it would be great to avoid absolute sizes, like width=25% for each of them.

Space between bars should be 5px.

## What i have

http://jsfiddle.net/5uzbxvss/1/

## html

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="title">
        <h3>Text</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="bars">
        <div class="outer">
            <div id="task_bar_1" class="inner">
                0%
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="task_bar_2" class="inner">
                0%
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="task_bar_3" class="inner">
                0%
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="outer">
            <div id="task_bar_4" class="inner">
                0%
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

## css

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.container {
}

.title {
    float: left;
}

.container h3 {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-top: 2px;
}

.bars {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.outer {
    background-color: grey;
    padding: 3px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    float: left;
}

.inner {
    background-color: orange;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Is it for modern browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS tables:

- Make `.container` a table as wide as the body:

  ```css
  .container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  ```
- Make `.title` a cell of that table, and set its width to the minimum required by its content:

  ```css
  .title {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  ```
- `.bars` will be wrapped inside an anonymous table-cell, which will cover all remaining space left by `.title`
- Make `.bars` a table as wide as the anonymous table-cell, distribute its width equally among the cells (ignoring their content), and add 5px separation between the cells:

  ```css
  .bars {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-spacing: 5px;
  }
  ```
- Make `.outer` cells of that table:

  ```css
  .outer {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  ```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
.title {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.title h3 {
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
.bars {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}
.outer {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 3px;
  display: table-cell;
}
.inner {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>Text</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="bars">
    <div class="outer">
      <div id="task_bar_1" class="inner">0%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <div id="task_bar_2" class="inner">0%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <div id="task_bar_3" class="inner">0%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="outer">
      <div id="task_bar_4" class="inner">0%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the flexible box solution for your problem. Create a flexbox container and assign `flex-grow: 1` to each of the div nested within.

Supports all modern browsers + IE11 :P [**Browser Support**](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.container {} .title {
  float: left;
}
.container h3 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-top: 2px;
}
.bars {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex; /* Add */
}
.outer {
  background-color: grey;
  padding: 3px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left;
  flex-grow: 1; /* Add */
}
.inner {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1 /* Add */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="title">
    <h3>I am a very long text to test it</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="bars">
    <div class="outer">
      <div id="task_bar_1" class="inner">
        0%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="outer">
      <div id="task_bar_2" class="inner">
        0%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="outer">
      <div id="task_bar_3" class="inner">
        0%
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="outer">
      <div id="task_bar_4" class="inner">
        0%
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is cool. Thank you! But.. is there any solution for older ones (ideally IE8)?

Comment: You can use JavaScript to find the offset width of the text and then calculate the width of the remaining. IE8 is too old to develop for. Start developing for IE10+.